# I need some help with analysing this differential amp

Tags: amplifier, analog, integrated-circuit

I'm having some trouble with analysing a differential amp. The amp and its associated operating parameters are in this link (question 1)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJHlG.jpg

What have I done so far?

Well I've tried using large signal analysis to get the bias currents in M5, M3, M4 and M6. I can find them for M5 and M6, but can only get expressions containing \$V_{o1}\$ and \$V_{o2}\$ ( i.e. \$V_o = V_{o2} - V_{o1}\$) for M3 and M4 bias currents. I also know that I know that the sum of all these bias currents is equal to 5mA.

I thought this was a pretty good start. What next?

Well, the next thing I looked at was a small signal analysis. I was hoping to draw my model up and derive some equations that I could piece together the voltage gain with - that's how it works normally.

My small signal model is drawn correctly, but I can't seem to get any traction in deriving expressions with \$v_{o1}\$, \$v_{o2}\$, \$v_{i1}\$ and \$v_{i2}\$.

I've been at this for a while now, could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This circuit is a little bit tricky because \$g_{m1} \neq g_{m2} \$.

The transistors M5 and M6 are only for biasing, they take away some current from M3 and M4 thereby increasing the gain of the amplifier. The problem is that these current sources are not equal. The current source I1 is only for biasing.

For the small-signal analysis only M1 through M4 are required.

Denoting the voltage at the sources of M1 and M2 by vx one gets
$$
 -g_{m1} (v_{i1} - vx) - g_{m2 }(v_{i2} - vx) = 0
$$
which can be rearranged as follows
$$
vx = \frac{g_{m1} v_{i1} + g_{m2} v_{i2}}{g_{m1} + g_{m2}}
$$
If \$g_{m1}\$ was equal to \$ g_{m2} \$ vx would be the common mode voltage \$(v_{i1} + v_{i2})/2\$. However this is not the case here.

Using vx we are now able to calculate the drain current
$$
i_{d1} = - i_{d2} = (v_{i1} - vx) \cdot g_{m1}
$$

In order to get the gain we have to find the output voltages, which is left as an exercise since it shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: Ah! Right! Through this post and the one below, I was able to gain some more insight on how the problem worked and solved it just now. I just have to do some numerical checking on OrCad - I think some of my numbers are a bit off, but pretty sure my analysis is spot on. Thanks so much for taking the time.

Comment: _This circuit is a little bit tricky because \$g_{m1} \neq g_{m2} \$._ — I disagree; \$g_{m1} \$ does in fact equal \$ g_{m2} \$, _**if**_ we assume that the DC bias level at the gates of M1 and M2 are equal (which seems like a safe assumption in this case).

Comment: As soon as the load for M1 and M2 is different a difference between the drain currents turns into a slight difference between the gms. The common-mode rejection is degraded, which can even be measured. However, assuming gm1 = gm2 could be sufficient to get a good approximation.

Comment: Yes, if diode-connected M3 and M4 were not present, due to nonzero \$ \lambda_{1}, \lambda_{2} \$, there exists a difference in drain currents for M1 and M2; however, M3 and M4 present 1/\$g_{m}\$ resistances in parallel with the respective drain resistances of M1, M2, significantly diminishing the channel-length modulation effect. In fact, I did a hand analysis of the original circuit in question and a hand analysis of a more simplified circuit given my comments above, and my simplified analysis yields a gain which is only off by about 0.6%.

Answer (score 0):

Watch these videos which explains the design of differential amplifiers

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLK2eyR1C9gjrMCVXRvKhY7CjNZYGCgMnY

I had designed mine recently and these videos really helped me to understand and design. There are certain analysis in the video lecture that explains about gain and relevant design criteria to achieve such a gain. The circuit diagram explained in the video are of a typical differential amplifier stage which is not exactly same as yours but gives you an insight on the design process. If you further have doubts comment here once again, I will help you as much as I know.